# Read table where the first few rows should become variables of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Year  | 2022 | 2022 | 2023
Month | Nov  | Dec  | Jan
  1   | -2.9 | -4.1 | -3.5
 ...  |  ... |  ... |  ...
  n   | -4.5 | -3.4 |  0.2
```

From this, I would like to generate a dataframe with variables "Year", "Month" and "ind" (indicating the integer in the first column). I do not know a priori how large n is. So the result should look like this:

```
Year | Month | ind | value  
-----|-------|-----|-------
2022 |  Nov  |  1  | -2.9
 ... |  ...  | ... |  ...
2022 |  Nov  |  n  | -4.5
2022 |  Dec  |  1  | -4.1
 ... |  ...  | ... |  ...
2022 |  Dec  |  n  | -3.4
2023 |  Jan  |  1  | -3.5
 ... |  ...  | ... |  ...
2023 |  Jan  |  n  | -0.2
```

Since I am relatively new to R, I have no idea where to start looking and would appreciate any advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the function `pivot_longer` from the 'tidyr' package. An example is provided below. The intermediate steps are there to reshape the input data into a form suitable for `pivot_longer` to work, and there is no need to know `n` in advance. You can find more details about `pivot_longer` by typing `?tidyr::pivot_longer` in the R console.

```
# install.packages("tidyr")  # install the package if you haven't already
library(tidyr)

data <- rbind(
  c("Year", 2022, 2022, 2023),
  c("Month", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan"),
  c(1, -2.9, -4.1, -3.5),
  c(2, -4.5, -3.4, 0.2),
  c(3, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0)
)
data
#      [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
# [1,] "Year"  "2022" "2022" "2023"
# [2,] "Month" "Nov"  "Dec"  "Jan" 
# [3,] "1"     "-2.9" "-4.1" "-3.5"
# [4,] "2"     "-4.5" "-3.4" "0.2" 
# [5,] "3"     "-1"   "-2"   "-3"  


df0 <- data.frame(t(data))
df0
#     X1    X2   X3   X4 X5
# 1 Year Month    1    2  3
# 2 2022   Nov -2.9 -4.5 -1
# 3 2022   Dec -4.1 -3.4 -2
# 4 2023   Jan -3.5  0.2 -3


df1 <- data.frame(df0[-1, ])
colnames(df1) <- df0[1, ]
df1
#   Year Month    1    2  3
# 2 2022   Nov -2.9 -4.5 -1
# 3 2022   Dec -4.1 -3.4 -2
# 4 2023   Jan -3.5  0.2 -3


final_df <- pivot_longer(df1, cols = -c("Year", "Month"), names_to = "ind", values_to = "value")
final_df
# # A tibble: 9 × 4
# Year  Month ind   value
# <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 2022  Nov   1     -2.9 
# 2 2022  Nov   2     -4.5 
# 3 2022  Nov   3     -1   
# 4 2022  Dec   1     -4.1 
# 5 2022  Dec   2     -3.4 
# 6 2022  Dec   3     -2   
# 7 2023  Jan   1     -3.5 
# 8 2023  Jan   2     0.2  
# 9 2023  Jan   3     -3
```